# UISearchBar issue with iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar

We have added an accessory view on right side of the search text field of UISearchBar.
We have developed our app with base SDK iOS 6, in iOS 6 all thing works well, but when we install the same app on iOS 7, the right accessory view of search text field is not being shown.

Please let me know how can we can resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes some of the component like `UISwitch`, `accessory` view of `iOS 6` won't be visible in `iOS 7` and **vise-versa**, if you use those UI component by **drag-n-drop** in Interface builder.

Here is three ways to use UI Component properly in `iOS 7 & iOS 6` and previous version

1. Create such component programmatically and set the frame properly and add those view into main view as subview and run app in any version of iOS smoothly.
2. Create two separate projects for `iOS 6` and below & for `iOS 7` and later.
3. And the third is extension of first one , upgrade your project into `iOS7` and build it in the same and run it in the `iOS 6` and below, you will fill some UI component to not properly aligned, align those manually by setting frame and also you may find some UI component invisible, so do as first point says. create those UI component programmatically.

Comment: Hi Suryakant, can you explain option 1 in detail, I added an UISearchBar programmatically by setting frame, but issue is not resolved.

Comment: you mean to say you added UISearchBar bar after alloc init. can you please tell me how you added accessory view?

Comment: yes after alloc-initing the searchbar added it to self.view and then added the right view to search field of bar.

Comment: now it's depend on the view that you are setting as inputAccessoryView, so please write about that view?

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed now by subclassing the UISearchBar and overriding the layoutSubviews method to find the search text field and assign the rightView of text field.